# How to do a SQL Server 2016 continuous upgrade

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-2016

I watched this [channel9 video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DataDriven/SQLServer2016/Upgrade-and-Migration), and it mentioned you could now do a continuous upgrade to MS SQL Server. This allows you have a side by side install and it will keep the databases in sync until you have fully migrated all of your apps. I can't find anything else online about this process. Is this called something else or does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use several mechanisms to do this.  DB Mirroring, Availability Groups, Log Shipping.  I prefer DB mirroring, its cut and dry and when you are ready to move to the new server you just fail over to it.

Comment: Side by side upgrades can be accomplished in a number of ways, including log shipping, mirroring, Availability Groups, replication, even manual backup/restore. I haven't watched it, but it sounds like the video promises some magical "side by side upgrade" button or wizard, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Look for the term "rolling upgrades" and SQL Server, there are a few articles written about rolling upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous upgrade referenced in that video was specific to the Upgrade Advisor tool. The tool has since been renamed [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/prepare-for-upgrade-by-running-data-migration-assistant?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

More content on upgrades here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15